# Django Rest Framework how to return detail not found on all invalid urls?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django 1.7

DRF 3.3.2

Python 2.7

I want to return a 404 Response with `{'detail': 'Not found'.}` whenever I  enter an invalid url.

However I get this only when I enter a valid url with invalid lookup parameters.

For example, if I make a GET request on:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/boxes/3e1659f3-9238-4b8f-a580-9b096d95bbfa/

i will get the requested object.

If I do the same thing with:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/boxes/3e1659f3-9238-4b8f-a580-9b096d95bbfajibbersihherelalalalalalala/

I will get a 404 with `{'detail': 'Not found'.}` message in the body.

If i try the same thing with this url:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/boxesevenbiggerjibberish

I will get a 404 with this error:

[image]

which will break my app.

So the question is, how do I set up my urls so that every invalid url is handled with the `{'detail': 'Not found'.}` message (which won't break my app).

**UPDATE**

The given answer will set a custom 404 view for your entire project (all aps).

If you want to set a custom 404 for a particular app inside a project, (e.g. you want your API to return json, but you want your app to return some custom template), then you can set a urlpattern to catch everything:

myapp/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    ...,
    url(r'^.*/$', views.error_page, name='error_page')
]
```

Make sure that the url is the last pattern (otherwise every url will call your custom error_page view).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom 404 view and assign it to django's [handler404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.handler404). This could look like this (not tested):

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import handler404
from myapp import views

handler404 = views.error_page
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status

@api_view()
def error_page(request):
    return Response({'detail': 'Not found'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: @BoldMarshmallow, why do you think the `api_view` won't work?

Comment: I apologize, it does work. Yesterday for some reason it broke my code, but now that I'm checking it again, everything seems to be fine. I must have made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: For anyone else having this issue, You should also have Debug = False in settings for this to work.